# Finding maximum number k such that for all combinations of k pairs, we have k different elements in each combination

Tags: algorithm

We are given N pairs. Each pair contains two numbers. We have to find maximum number K such that if we take any combination of J (1<=J<=K) pairs from the given N pairs, we have at least J different numbers in all those selected J pairs. We can have more than one pair same.

For example, consider the pairs
(1,2)
(1,2)
(1,2)
(7,8)
(9,10)
For this case K = 2, because for K > 2, if we select three pairs of (1,2), we have only two different numbers i.e 1 and 2.

Checking for each possible combination starting from one will take a very large amount of time. What would be an efficient algorithm for solving the problem?

Comment: I believe the problem is connected to the Set Cover problem, but this problem seems easier. I believe there is a polynomial solution for it.

Comment: @Jack Not at all. Just a problem I am stuck up at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a graph with one vertex for each number and one edge for each pair.

If this graph is a chain or a tree, we have the number of "numbers", equal to number of "pairs" plus one, After removing any number of edges from this graph, we never get less vertexes than edges.

Now add a single cycle to this chain/tree. There is equal number of vertexes and edges. After removing any number of edges from this graph, again we never get less vertexes than edges.

Now add any number of disconnected components, each should not contain more than one cycle. Once again, we never get less vertexes than edges after removing any number of edges.

Now add a second cycle to any of disconnected components. After removing all other components. at last we have more edges than vertexes (more pairs than numbers).

All this leads to the conclusion that K+1 is exactly the number of edges in the smallest possible subgraph, consisting of two cycles and, possibly, a chain, connecting these cycles.

#### Algorithm:

For each connected component, find the shortest cycle going through every node with Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

Then for each non-overlapping pair of cycles (in single component), use Dijkstra’s algorithm, starting from any node with at least 3 edges in one cycle, to find shortest path to other cycle; and compute a sum of lengths of both cycles and a shortest path, connecting them. For each overlapping pair of cycles, just compute the number of their edges.

Now find the minimum length of all these subgraphs. And subtract 1.

The above algorithm computes K if there is at least one double-cycle component in the graph. If there are no such components, K = N.

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to MinCut/MaxFlow. Here is a try to reduce it to MinCut/MaxFlow:

```
- Produce one vertex for each number
- Produce one vertex for each pair
- Produce an edge from number i to a pair if the number is present in the pair, weight 1
- Produce a source node and connect it to all numbers, weight 1 for each connection
- Produce a sink node and connect it to all numbers, weight 1 for each connection
```

Running MaxFlow on this should give you the number `K`, since any set of three pairs which only contains two numbers in total, will be "blocked" by the constrains on the outgoing edges from the number.

I am not sure whether this is the fastest solution. There might also be a matroid hidden in there somewhere, I think. In that case there is a greedy approach. But I cannot find a proof for the matroid properties of the sets you are constructing.

Comment: It does seem related but in the example this would give 4, 1 unit from 1 to the first (1, 2), 1 unit from 2 to the second (1, 2), 1 unit from 7 to (7, 8), and one unit from 9 to (9, 8).

Comment: @btilly: Ok, I misread the question. I was thinking, you would also select a subset of the pairs with cardinality `K`. But you are only taking the number and are always considering the whole set. In that case of course my idea is invalid.

Comment: @btilly: Also of course, if you are not actually considering subsets, the remark about the matroid properties is invalid.

Comment: @btilly: Looking at this some more, there may still be a modification possible by introducing nodes for the numbers and nodes for possible `K`s. However I do not have the time right now to work it out. Also my intuition tells me, that this most likely will be a polynomial reduction with a very high exponent at best. Maybe I'll add another answer when I have more time later, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress on it, but not yet an efficient solution.  However it may point the way.

Make a graph whose points are pairs, and connect any pair of points if they share a number.  Then for any subgraph, the number of numbers in it is the number of vertices minus the number of edges.  Therefore your problem is the same as locating the smallest subgraph (if any) that has more edges than vertices.

A minimal subgraph that has the same number of edges and vertices is a cycle.  Therefore the graphs we're looking for are either 2 cycles that share one or more vertices, or else 2 cycles which are connected by a path.  There are no other minimal types possible.

You can locate and enumerate cycles fairly easily with a breadth-first search.  There may be a lot of them, but this is doable.  Armed with that you can look for subgraphs of these subtypes.  (Enumerate minimal cycles, look for either pairs that share points, or which are connected.)  But that isn't guaranteed to be polynomial.  I suspect it will be something where on average it is pretty good, but the worst case is very bad.  However that may be more efficient than what you're doing now.

I keep on thinking that some kind of breadth-first search can find these in polynomial time, but I keep failing to see exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to finding the chord that chords the smallest cycle in the graph. A very naive algorithm would be:

Check if removal of an edge results in a cycle containing the vertices corresponding to the edge. If yes, then note down the length of the smallest cycle.